# Вопрос по фильтрации в Django

Tags: python, django

Пишу небольшое приложение, которое должно выводить из БД начисления и считать их сумму в зависимости от заданного периода.

Период определяется экземпляром фильтра, где переменные `start_date` и `end_date`, соответственно, начало и конец периода.

С выводом начислений в заданный период всё хорошо, а вот с подсчётом их суммы трудности (этим призвана заниматься функция `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)`, строка `context[sum]`), работает только при ручном вводе.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как значения переменных `start_date` и `end_date` извлечь из фильтра `ReportFilter` в view.py?

filters.py

```
class ReportFilter(FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='reporting_date',
                                           widget= forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
                                           lookup_expr='gt', label='Период начисления с  ')
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='reporting_date',
                                         widget= forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
                                         lookup_expr='lt', label='по   ')
```

Вьюха имеет вид:

views.py

```
class FinreportList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Accruals
    template_name = 'report.html'
    filter_class = ReportFilter
    context_object_name = 'taxes'
     
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, super().get_queryset())
        return self.filter.qs.all()
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = self.filte
        start_date = '2023-08-01'  ????
        end_date = '2023-09-01'    ????
        context['sum'] = Accruals.objects.filter(reporting_date__range=(start_date, end_date)).aggregate(Sum('accrued')).get('accrued__sum')
        return context
```